Public IP on proxmox VM, without NAT
On my Ubuntu NFTables server, I receive 2 links from two different ISPs.
In addition to the wan1 and wan2 ports, I also have the lan1 port, which is where I have a proxmox server with some VMs already running, with external access through SNAT on the Ubuntu server that I use as a router.
So far ok. Everything working.
The problem is that now I need to create an Ubuntu VM on the proxmox, which should receive a specific public IP, and not an IP from the lan1 subnet.
In this case, on the server I use as a router, I need to make this IP be used directly, without the use of SNAT, by this new VM in the next.
The IP in question, for example, would be 222.22.222.13 which is currently configured on wan2 of the router server (proxmox is connected to that same server using lan1).
The router configuration is this:
network:
ethernets:
    wan1:
        addresses:
        - 111.31.111.2/28
        - 111.31.111.3/28
        - 111.31.111.4/28
        - 111.31.111.5/28
        - 111.31.111.6/28
        - 111.31.111.7/28
        - 111.31.111.8/28
        - 111.31.111.9/28
        - 111.31.111.10/28
        - 111.31.111.11/28
        - 111.31.111.12/28
        - 111.31.111.13/28
        - 111.31.111.14/28
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
            search: []
        routes:
        - to: default
          via: 111.31.111.1
          metric: 100
        - to: default
          via: 111.31.111.1
          metric: 100
          table: 100
        routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.10.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.20.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.30.0/24
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.40.0/24
          table: 100
    wan2:
        addresses:
        - 222.63.222.10/29
        - 222.63.222.11/29
        - 222.63.222.12/29
        - 222.63.222.13/29
        - 222.63.222.14/29
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
            search: []
        routes:
        - to: default
          via: 222.63.222.9
          metric: 200
        - to: default
          via: 222.63.222.9
          metric: 200
          table: 200
        routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.10.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.20.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.30.0/24
          table: 200
        - from: 192.168.40.0/24
          table: 200
    lan1:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.10.1/24
    lan2:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.20.1/24
    lan3:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.30.1/24
    lan4:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.40.1/24
version: 2

And NFTables does SNAT for the server with proxmox and for its various VMs.
And now I need to use the public ip 222.22.222.13 directly on the interface of a VM, so that it doesn't do NAT and uses the direct ip.
Proxmox config:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp4s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.10/24
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        bridge-ports enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

assign the VM interface to this new interface that I created in proxmox, and in the VM I configured the ip 222.22.222.13/29 and the gateway 222.22.222.9
but it didn't work.
I read some publications, but I couldn't understand and configure it.

" I need to make this IP be used directly, without the use of SNAT" - hmmmm. That seems a VERY odd requirement.

Regardless of the oddity of the requirement, it seems it is the job for the proxy-arp. However, this is quite clumsy and tricky technology, and you certainly must know what you are doing. I don't know how to set it up properly with netplan (as I am convinced "Ubuntu Server" is really called "Debian" which doesn't use netplan).
